# Is it possible to create tablename in Datastage using String and Date?

Tags: string, date, variables, datastage

I want to make a dynamic table name using variable with date and string value in Datastage.
For example for today :
`PROFIT_MARGIN_20150918`
For tomorrow it will be :
`PROFIT_MARGIN_20150919`
The date will be generated automatically with format `YYYYMMDD` by date in Datastage and the `PROFIT_MARGIN_` is a template table name.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the Database connector, you can use a parameter for your table name.  Simply pass the Datastage job (that is calling the database) the constructed table name (from a sequence), place the parameter in the Table Name field or #parametername# in the INSERT/UPDATE statements and it will use it.

Comment: Yes. I know this thing. The problem is : I don't know how to make the variable value. What function should I use to fetch the date? And how to append the string with the date?

Answer (score 0):

there are so many ways to do it best one is -
if you are using a sequencer, you can use command activity to get date from linux and pass the generated value as a parameter to job

Thanks
Atul Singh